# Angular, How to add class to tag has already some css classes before form the html template directly?

Tags: angular, angular9

I want to write code like this
note: the classes in the **class** (style13 style121 style541) property i don't have any control on it
and i want to add other class from variable on the TS

example:

```
<div class="style13 style121 style541" [class]="varInTheCode" [class.other-style3]="true">
...
<div>
```

TS

```
export class MyDataTableComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    varInTheCode:string = "other-style1 other-style2";

}
```

I hope the result in the browser will be like this:

```
<div class="style13 style121 style541 other-style1 other-style2 other-style3" ...>
...
<div>
```

but the problem always [class] replace the class!

can i do it?

Comment: Use [ngClass]. It won't replace existing class. It will add new class in that.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here:

- Use Ivy(Angular 9^): it should work out of the box there
- Use `[ngClass]` directive instead of `[class]` property binding

Comment: what is  Ivy(Angular 9^)??

Comment: Ivy is the code name for Angular's next-generation compilation and rendering pipeline. It's used by default starting from Angular 9